# Coarsening a 2.5D triangulation

Tags: geometry, triangulation, delaunay, douglas-peucker

I have a 2D-delaunay-triangulation where each vertex is labeled with an elevation. I now want to remove vertices from the triangulation without making big changes to the form (analogous to douglas-peucker for polylines).

[image: 2.5D delaunay triangulation]

There are a lot of mesh-coarsening algorithms for 3D-meshes. But isn't there something simpler for my task?

Comment: How did you make 2D-delaunay-triangulation on these 3D points?

Comment: Just make a 2D-delaunay-triangulation on XY and ignore Z. The assumption made is that we only have 2.5D and not real 3D.

Answer (score 0):

Do not remove points from your existing model. Instead construct a second one. Start with a few convex hull points and then refine the new model in a divide and conquer style until comparison with the original model yields that the specified error bound is kept. I have implemented it like that in the  [Fade](http://www.geom.at/fade25d/html/classGEOM__FADE25D_1_1EfficientModel.html) library and it works well. You can try my 2.5D Douglas-Peucker implementation if you want, the student license is free.

But best possible output quality requires also that feature lines are detected, simplified and conserved. This is more involved, I work on that topic and hope that I can provide results soon.

Comment: Do you have any results on feature line detection, yet?

Comment: Not in this context because the typical application is creating TINs from terrain scans. These are noisy and natural terrains do not have clear features anyway (except buildings which are not 2.5D), thus I was a bit lazy about that. But implementing features is not hard, I have done that in other settings. It depends on your needs.